# PIP module installs in cmd but python cant see it

Tags: python, keras, pip

I have looked this up, no-one else has had the same issue.

I was installing Keras and in the Command Prompt, it said it installed just fine; however, in python it just gives me this error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Comment: you can check where the module is installed, also check if you are using the same python version where u installed the module.

Comment: python help('keras'), it will show the location if it is installed.

Comment: @LakshyaSrivastava yep, thats it, there was a windows store python and a normal one and pip went to the windows store one

Comment: I didn't get it, the windows store and normal one?, if it not a burden try to remove all python version and get a clean new one.

Comment: Or you can use pycharm create a virtual environment and install whatever module u like.

Comment: Don't use the `pip` script, ever. Instead be explicit about the targeted Python interpreter and call _pip_'s executable module: `path/to/python -m pip somecommand` -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/